# Не проходит пароль после исполнения скрипта создания системного пользователя

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, unix, shell

Добрый день! Имеется скрипт автоматического создания системного пользователя.

```
#!/bin/bash

# скрипт создания системного пользователя
if [ $(id --user) -eq 0 ]; then

    # ввод имени нового пользователя
    read -p "Enter username : " username
    # ввод пароля для нового пользователя
    read -s -p "Enter password : " password
    # проверка наличия существующего пользователя
    egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$username exists!"
        exit 1
    else

        pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $passwd)
        # добавление пользователя с паролем
        useradd -m -p $pass $username
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add user"

    fi
else
    # предупреждение
    echo " Only root may add a user to the system"
    exit 2
fi

exit
```

После выполнения скрипта создается пользователь, но не проходит пароль.

Comment: А какой пароль вы вводите в скрипт? И какой потом пробуете использовать?

Comment: пароль - admin.

Comment: Попробуйте уменьшить "соль" до 2 символов

Comment: спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Кстати, а почему сразу не писать на `perl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте уменьшить "соль" до 2 символов